# What does ".refptr." mean in a mingw64 .def file?

Tags: dll, linker, mingw-w64

Investigating a crashing dll linkage with mingw64 4.9.2 on Windows 7, I looked into the generated `.def` file that is fed to the linker and saw that the first 391 of the 1419 exports all had names of the form `.refptr.FooBar`. The same build, using mingw64 4.6.3 linked successfully, and in that case the `.def` file contained no such exports.

Can anyone tell me what these `.refptr.` prefixes mean? Googling was to no avail.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-03/msg00858.html

Comment: @HansPassant ...also prompts a fix for the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant portion of Hans Passant's GCC patch link:

> This feature is required for upcoming new cygwin x64 target, which
>   uses full 48-bit available address-space of x64 Windows.
>   The cygwin-target depends on pseudo-relocation-feature, which operates
>   on instruction relocations.  This can lead for x86_64 to issues, due
>   instructions are in general signed-32bit-pc-relative relocated.  So
>   distances can become too wide for pseudo-relocation.
>   Due for functions we generate anyway on pe-coff targets jump-stubs, we
>   just need to make sure that variables are accessed via
>   reference-pointer-variables.  So we add for them in medium model
>   .refptr-variables.

I found that my linker crash could be remedied without collateral damage 
simply by deleting all the `.refptr.` prefixes from the `.def` file. 
(Clearly one would not always be so lucky)